# Mozilla Thunderbird "Get Mail" doesn't get all the mail from the beginning

Tags: gmail, thunderbird

I have installed Mozilla Thunderbird, now it updated to version 24.5.0 .

I am trying to download all the emails from my Gmail account to Thunderbird. The problem is that only emails from 8 August 2013 are being downloaded, whereas my actual first emails date to 17 October 2011.

How can I download the remaining ( older ) emails too ?

Comment: @pnuts - I don't know how to answer about the order of volume. But the issue remains that only emails from that day in 2013 are being transferred, and emails I am receiving today are coming to TBird too. I expected Thunderbird will start transferring emails from the very first one in the beginning, and not skip two years forward.

Answer (score 1):

Check your POP settings (`Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP`).

[image: POP settings]

Check that the option for **all mail** is selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the same Gmail POP account with multiple email clients you need to enable recent mode in order to let each email client access all of the messages in that account. You can do that by replacing `username@gmail.com` with `recent:username@gmail.com` as the username in *Tools* → *Account Settings* → *Server Settings*.